# Set page title when viewing PDF through php script

Tags: php, html, pdf

I am using this code to view an PDF file in php instead of just opening it in an browser.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{
    require_once('includes/db_connect.php');

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['id']);
    $attest = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['attest']);
    $heat = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['heat']);
    $mat = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['mat']);
    $dikte = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['dikte']);

    $file = '../thure/uploads/attesten/'.$id.'.pdf';

    $filename = 'Certificaat plaat '.$id.' met '.$attest.' heat '.$heat.' '.$mat.' '.$dikte.'mm.pdf';

    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    @readfile($file);
}
```

The title of the page as Shown in Explorer, Chrome etc. is the name of the php file. How can I set an custom name (same as PDF) here?

When I use the code below the pdf is shown as plain text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Torza</title>
</head>
```